# Question Regarding Atiyah&Macdonald Chapter 2 Ex.10

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism

I am a bit confused by a step of a solution in commutative algebra.

So the context is that $a$ is an ideal of $A$, contained in the Jacobson Ideal of $A$, $M$ is an $A$ module and $N$ is a finitely generated $A$ module, $f$ is a homomorphism from $M$ to $N$, and the question asks us to prove that if the induced map from $M/aM$ to $N/aN$ is surjective, then so is $f$.

I understand the second part of the solution where we use Nakayama's Lemma, but the first part of the proof says $(N/{\rm Im}(f)/a(N/{\rm Im}(f))$ is a zero module, which I don't see why.

I am not super fluent with group homomorphisms' induced results, so I would really appreciate it if you could indicate which theorems/facts/intuitions were used here or can be generally helpful when dealing with homomorphisms and quotient (of quotient) groups.

Thank you.

Comment: Notice that $\mathfrak a(N/{\rm Im}(f))=(\mathfrak aN+{\rm Im}(f))/{\rm Im}(f)$. Thus
$$(N/{\rm Im}(f))/a(N/{\rm Im}(f))=N/(\mathfrak aN+{\rm Im}(f)).$$ Now using the surjectivity of the induced map, it is easy to deduce that $N/(\mathfrak aN+{\rm Im}(f))$ is the zero module.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Thank you for the advice. I have edited the tags and tried to change the title. Regarding your solution, I think I see what you are doing here, but why is $a(N/Im(f))=(aN+Im(f))/Im(f)$ instead of $=aN/aIm(f)$? Is it the module $a(n+Im(f))=an+aIm(f)=aN/aIm(f)$ where $n$ runs over N? Or maybe these two are equal, but I am not sure how. I am sorry my algebra background is not really solid, so I am still processing in an elementary way.

Comment: @flypig  $N/\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is an $A$-module, so at least $a(N/\operatorname{Im}(f))\subset N/\operatorname{Im}(f)$, the equivalent relation is always module $\operatorname{Im}(f)$. Moreover, $\mathfrak{a}N$ may not contain ${\rm Im}(f)$, so you should add ${\rm Im}(f)$ to the numerator.

Comment: @flypig If $I\subset A $ is an ideal and $M$ an $A$-module, then $$IM=\{\sum_i c_im_i\mid c_i\in I\}$$(finite linear combinations). Same definition applies to $a (N/ Im (f))$. Furthermore, notice that the multiplication is defined by $c (x+Im (f))=cx+ Im(f)$. (See Yang Pei's comment as well.)

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Ah I see! My confusion was caused by the definition of the product of an ideal and a module. Now it is clear! Thank you!

Comment: @YangPei Thank you! That is a quite intuitive way of interpreting it!